# Overlap with a translucent div in a responsive website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been [working on a self-project](https://github.com/kaushikthedeveloper/subreddit-clone/tree/header) to duplicate the [reddit page for javascript](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/) using the JSON data available. But am not able to replicate the behaviour of the original website in its `header section`, where the `header` is responsive (behaviour when screen size is decreased).

[image]

[GIF : how the original website header section works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GEnZ.jpg).

***The problem :***

1. **Overlap** the right side (Login page options) over the left hand side. The overlapping is such that the ***behind text is not shown***. I have managed to do the ***overlapping***, but since the background for the `divs` are `translucent`, the ***behind text too shows***. Can't think of any solution for this.

[GIF : my header (behind text seen)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONGw6.jpg)

2. The `navbar elements` transcend down when space is not enough. This is not how it is in the original, where they get hidden by the `more` and `Login section`. I cannot figure out how to go about having it in a *single row*.

[GIF : my header (header elements move down)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQbEA.jpg)

---

A smaller, similar sample snippet :

```css
.custom-header-full{
    background: rgba(255,255,0,1);
}

/* Top */
.custom-top-header-container{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);       /* translucent */
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
}
#top-right-div{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="navbar navbar-static-top custom-header-full">

    <!-- TOPMOST header with Links and Login/Signup -->
    <div class="navbar-header custom-top-header-container">
        <!-- Left side with various links -->
        <div id="top-left-div">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MY SUBREDDITS ▼</a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">POPULAR</a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ALL</a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">RANDOM</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Login/Signup on the right -->
        <div id="top-right-div">
            <span class="navbar-brand">Want to join?
                <a href="#">Log in or sign up</a>
                in seconds |
                <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench tools-icon"></button>
            </span>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

In case you want to check with the [full project, the link on Github](https://github.com/kaushikthedeveloper/subreddit-clone/tree/header).

**An interesting point to Note :** in the header, the left sided `titles` are being overlapped by the right sided `section`. So it is a smooth transaction where the possibility is such that even ***partial of the text is seen in a title*** when overlapped. Basically its not a matter of making the title element invisible by width as that would make the whole `title` invisible.

Ex :

- The title has `TODAYIL`
  [image]
- The title has `TODAYILEARNED` (whole of the title)
  [image]

Comment: You will probably want to be a bit clearer as to whether it has to be a pure CSS solution or not, especially given you reference Javascript. By the way, the original reddit header doesn't work as it's shown in your video under Firefox 54.

Comment: @Pyromonk : anything is fine. Would prefer a pure CSS solution, but if other methods make life easier, thats fine. And I didn't get what you meant by doesn't work.

Comment: I've already submitted a pure-CSS answer. I was actually wrong. The overlap functionality didn't work for me on the [reddit page for Javascript](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/). It now does. False alert.

Comment: Yeah, saw the fiddle code. Unfortunately busy right now. Can't explore further for the time being. Will check further when time permits. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Please check out [Briley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4996362/briley-hooper)'s solution that uses `flex` as well, as it is a bit less intrusive with regard to your original code samples.

Answer (score 9):

If you're able to use [CSS flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox), I think this solution works the way you want:

```css
.custom-header-full{
    background: rgba(255,255,0,1);
}

/* Top */
.custom-top-header-container{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);       /* translucent */
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
#top-left-div {
    flex: 1 1 0%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#top-right-div{
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="navbar navbar-static-top custom-header-full">

    <!-- TOPMOST header with Links and Login/Signup -->
    <div class="navbar-header custom-top-header-container">
        <!-- Left side with various links -->
        <div id="top-left-div">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MY SUBREDDITS ▼</a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">POPULAR</a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ALL</a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">RANDOM</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Login/Signup on the right -->
        <div id="top-right-div">
            <span class="navbar-brand">Want to join?
                <a href="#">Log in or sign up</a>
                in seconds |
                <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench tools-icon"></button>
            </span>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

What I did:

1. Make `.custom-top-header-container` `display:flex` to ensure the left and right display side-by-side.
2. Make `#top-right-div` only ever take up the space that its content needs (i.e. don't grow or shrink)
3. Make `#top-left-div` fill whatever space remains in the container, and use `overflow:hidden` to hide any content that might overlap with `#top-right-div` on small widths.
4. Set `#top-left-div` to `white-space: nowrap` to prevent links with spaces (like "My Subreddits") from breaking onto multiple lines when the screen shrinks small enough.

Comment: Nice. And good explanation. Just one more thing. If you could explain how the `flex: 1 1 0%;` and `flex: 0 0 auto;` work, would be great. And if my guess is not wrong, the `overflow:hidden` added helps to cover up the background elements even when its own background color is translucent right?

Comment: @KaushikNP, [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) takes in 3 parameters: [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow), [`flex-shrink`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink) and [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) (in that order). The pages I link to have good graphical examples that clearly illustrate the idea. Please keep [this](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) in mind if you target older browsers (click "Show all" to show all recorded browser versions).

Comment: @KaushikNP, the second question is more difficult to answer. One could just say "yes" and walk away, but that wouldn't be right. The [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) property defines what happens to element contents if they overflow their container's size. I recommend reading about the [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) and [the box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model), unless you have already.

Comment: Pyromonk pretty much covered it all. `flex: 1 1 0%` tells the browser "set the initial width at 0%, then grow or shrink as necessary to fill horizontal space" (the `0%` ensures that the element doesn't take up any width at all by default). `flex: 0 0 auto` says "set the initial width to whatever the natural width of this element's content is, and don't allow it to grow or shrink". The MDN article I linked to in my answer does a pretty good job of explaining the ins and outs of flexbox, I referenced it a lot when I was first getting started.

Answer (score 4):

I've managed to implement a pure-CSS solution without `flex` of what I assume you wanted to get.

I will highlight some of the changes I've made (the ones that don't directly pertain to the problem and could therefore be overlooked):

- Got rid of `.navbar`, `.navbar-static-top`, `.navbar-header`, `.custom-header-full` and `.custom-top-header-container`. Please find a way to overwrite their behaviour at your own time if you really need those classes. I can try to help if it proves too difficult.
- Removed CAPS LOCK from source and substituted it with `text-transform: uppercase;` inside the CSS file. This can really help in the future if one happens to fall asleep while adding a new navigation link.
- Substituted "▼" with an HTML entity (`&#9660;`). Modern browsers normally don't care, but it's still good practice.

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pLsvgeyr/) of the end result. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2):

A little hack can help you I guess. Try doing these CSS changes :

```
#top-right-div {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
    background: rgba(255,255,0,1);
}
```

And add `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);` to the `.navbar-brand` under `top-right-div` in html.

This would create an illusion of what you are trying to achieve.

```css
.custom-header-full{
    background: rgba(255,255,0,1);
}

/* Top */
.custom-top-header-container{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);       /* translucent */
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
#top-left-div {
    flex: 1 1 0%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#top-right-div{
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    background: rgba(255,255,0,1);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="navbar navbar-static-top custom-header-full">

    <!-- TOPMOST header with Links and Login/Signup -->
    <div class="navbar-header custom-top-header-container">
        <!-- Left side with various links -->
        <div id="top-left-div">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MY SUBREDDITS ▼</a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">POPULAR</a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ALL</a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">RANDOM</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Login/Signup on the right -->
        <div id="top-right-div">
            <span class="navbar-brand" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);">Want to join?
                <a href="#">Log in or sign up</a>
                in seconds |
                <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench tools-icon"></button>
            </span>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting tweak with adding the background to the `navbar-brand`. Hadn't thought of that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for Overlap you can use  this style:

```
.custom-header-full{
    background: rgba(255,255,0,1);
}

/* Top */
.custom-top-header-container{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7); 
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
}
#top-right-div {
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
}

#top-left-div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 53%;
    float: left;
}
```

Like :[demo](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FN3GYB4TH9D8)

and other device you can use media queries Like :

```
 @media (min-width:0px) and (max-width:799px) { add style  }
```

write style according to device.

i thing it's helpful for you.

Comment: Um, the overlapping does not work. It just shifts the tabs down.

Comment: i thing you can adjust according to the device use  media queries and add style: like small font-size and five `#top-left-div , #top-right-div {width:100%} `

Comment: Could you pls elaborate?

Comment: like in mobile or tab : `@media (min-width:0px) and (max-width:799px) { #top-left-div , #top-right-div {width:100%}  }` this css working only if you device size max-width:799px.

Answer (score 0):

To handle the stretching issues. Try to inspect the website using responsive option

[responsive button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qS6y4.png)

Then you can know the dimension of the screen when the texts are overlapping or the navigation bar is two line high

[get the width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IY5Bp.png)

So at last you can add your media query to create differences from the desktop website. In case it's 450px

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    /* Add your css specification here. */
}
```